# Reordering of WooCommerce order columns

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to reorder WooCommerce order page columns using the following function, but without success. Does someone know if it is still possible with the current version of WooCommerce and if I made a mistake somewhere?

```
function new_orders_columns( $columns = array() ) {

// Hide the columns
if( isset($columns['order-total']) ) {
    // Unsets the columns which you want to hide
    unset( $columns['order-number'] );
    unset( $columns['order-date'] );
    unset( $columns['order-status'] );
    unset( $columns['order-total'] );
    unset( $columns['order-actions'] );
}

// Add new columns
$columns['order-status'] = __( 'État', 'Text Domain' );
$columns['order-number'] = __( 'Numéro', 'Text Domain' );
$columns['order-actions'] = __( '&nbsp;', 'Text Domain' );
$columns['order-total'] = __( 'Total', 'Text Domain' );
$columns['order-date'] = __( 'Date de commande', 'Text Domain' );


return $columns;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'new_orders_columns' );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
/**
 * Change the my accounts orders column order.
 * 
 * @param  array $columns - The columns.
 * @return array
 */
function so_58454709_reorder_orders_columns( $columns ) {

    // Unsets the columns which you want to hide
    unset( $columns['order-number'] );
    unset( $columns['order-date'] );
    unset( $columns['order-status'] );
    unset( $columns['order-total'] );
    unset( $columns['order-actions'] );

    $new_columns = array(
        'order-status'  => __( 'État', 'Text Domain' ),
        'order-number'  => __( 'Numéro', 'Text Domain' ),
        'order-actions' => __( '&nbsp;', 'Text Domain' ),
        'order-total'   => __( 'Total', 'Text Domain' ),
        'order-date'    => __( 'Date de commande', 'Text Domain' ),
    );

    return array_merge( $new_columns, $columns );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_orders_columns', 'so_58454709_reorder_orders_columns' );
```

For me, this snippet results in the following:
[image: Resulting My Orders table]

Comment: Welcome back to you!

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec! I probably still won't be around much. I must've really be procrastinating hard this day. ;)